# JS: asynchronous api, final result is always empty

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

i'm using asynchronous service and get data from. This part is ok, but when i try set this data and then get from object - empty value.
PLease check my code below, why getPage() return false?

```
var PageName = function() {
    this.page = false;

    this.getPage = function() {
        return this.page;
    };

    this.setPage = function(pageId) {
        this.page = pageId;
        console.log(pageId); //Get correct result
    };

    this.savePage = function(callback) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('pageId', function (obj) {
            pageId = obj.pageId;
            callback(pageId);
        });
    };
};

var page = new PageName();
page.savePage(page.setPage);

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(page.getPage()); //always get default result - false

}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.setPage` needs to be bound to page. Look at the first example on this site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
Alternatively you could also not use `this` at all. Then you don't need to bind the function.
e.g.

```
var PageName = function() {
    var page = false;

    function getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    function setPage(pageId) {
        page = pageId;
    }
    function savePage(callback) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('pageId', function (obj) {
            setPage(obj.pageId);
            callback(obj.pageId);
        });
    }

    return {
      getPage: getPage,
      setPage: setPage,
      savePage: savePage
    };
}

var page = PageName();
page.savePage(function(pageId) {
    console.log("pageId = " + pageId);
    console.log("page.getPage() = " + page.getPage());
});
```

In this example I also removed the use of `setInterval` since I don't think it makes much sense.
btw. Here are some iteresting articles on javascript object creation patterns.
http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/some-Javascript-constructor-patterns
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687093/Understanding-JavaScript-Object-Creation-Patterns